# Using MediaSessionManager.OnActiveSessionsChangedListener on AndroidTV

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to listen for changes to the active media sessions on my Android TV (specifically to set my Hue lights into a sort of "movie mode"). On a normal Android device (4.3+) I'd set up a `NotificationListenerService` to allow me to call `MediaSessionManager.addOnActiveSessionsChangedListener()`.

The problem is that Android TV doesn't seem to have a UI to enable my `NotificationListenerService`, and there is nothing to handle `Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS`. Does anyone know of another approach to listen for media changes or a way to enable a `NotificationListenerService` on Android TV? This is just for my own use, so this doesn't need to be a scalable solution (adb is fine).

Comment: What player are you using? Android's [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)?

Comment: I'm not using any MediaPlayer. I'm not playing media myself. I'm listening for other apps playing media.

Comment: Was playing with this myself and came across your question. I've posted the answer for ADB. Out of curiosity though, did you find anything else?

Comment: I haven't, so it looks like I'm going the ADB route.

Comment: That's unfortunate. You'd think someone would have thought twice about shipping an Android product where it's impossible to create third party home screens that replicate basic platform functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an ADB shell:

1. Get the current list of enabled notification listeners:

> settings get secure enabled_notification_listeners

By default on my TV, this returns **com.google.android.leanbacklauncher/.notifications.NotificationMonitorService**.

2. Add yours to the list, separated by a colon.

> settings put secure enabled_notification_listeners **com.google.android.leanbacklauncher/.notifications.NotificationMonitorService**:*com.example/com.example.MyNotificationListenerService*

Comment: I am trying same thing to set my application as notification listener by using adb command but when i open "Notification Access" in android settings it still not enabled my application as a listener. Any thought about it ?

Comment: @user565 on a multiuser device, ensure that your `settings put` is targeted to the correct user.

Comment: Actually I am trying this on phone so it has an only single user by default

Comment: the number of users you're using is irrelevant. all android phones, starting in 5.0, are multiuser devices.

Comment: ok, Can you please tell me how to verify that the settings are set to which user?

Comment: use "pm list users" to find the user id; it's the first number on the line that includes your user name. then, you need to add "--user #" before the word "secure" in each of these commands.